# WorkflowScript: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am use the Jenkins docker container to run Jenkins.  I have this pipeline:

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

def wholeFileData
def ys = new YamlSlurper()

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    ...
```

... and I get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
   ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yamlslurper introduced in groovy v3.0. I think you have lower version of groovy in Jenkins. Better to use native step readYaml https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text